# OutOfMemoryException in wcf

Tags: vb.net, wcf

Am new to width web services I have windows mobile 5 application that I want pull 10000 records from a SQL 2005 database. Every time I click the sync button I get the OutOfMemoryException. He's there anything I need to do in web config to allow prevent this error?
My Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>

      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1572864"/>
  </system.web>
 <runtime>
    <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
  </runtime>
   <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>

      <service name="WcfServiceLibrary1.LocalDataCache1SyncService" behaviorConfiguration="WcfServiceLibrary1.LocalDataCache1SyncServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress ="http://fo me to know/LocalDataCache1SyncService/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address ="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.ILocalDataCache1SyncContract"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>

      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfServiceLibrary1.LocalDataCache1SyncServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

 <system.diagnostics>
      <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel" 
                    switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                    propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
               <add name="traceListener" 
                   type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
                   initializeData= "c:\log\Traces.svclog" />
            </listeners>
         </source>
      </sources>
   </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Bindings don't matter regarding a `OutOfMemoryException`. Probably the device (server?) doesn't have enough memory to handle the amount of data, though, it could be also some other problem. Depends on your code (and where the exception occurs).

Answer (score 0):

My problem was fix. Please see updated we.config. My windows mobile device have 4G storage and the server 1T with 10G of RAM.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CPXZMobileAssistantServer.My.MySettings.ServerCPXZMobile2005_Data1ConnectionString"
      connectionString="Your Data Source"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" />
    </diagnostics>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WindowsSecured" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CPXZMobileAssistantServer.LocalDataCache1SyncServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="CPXZMobileAssistantServer.LocalDataCache1SyncServiceBehavior"
              name="CPXZMobileAssistantServer.LocalDataCache1SyncService">
        <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WindowsSecured" bindingName="" contract="CPXZMobileAssistantServer.ILocalDataCache1SyncContract" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingName="" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://cpxzpos.com" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>

  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
                    switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                    propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener"
                        type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                        initializeData="c:\log\Traces.svclog"  />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>

</configuration>
```

Comment: The solution in this case was the configuration of the `WindowsSecured` `basicHttpBinding`; defining `max` values override default values.